# How to create a "view" domain object in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, dns, grails-orm

I'm trying to adapt a legacy database to a grails application and I'm not sure how can I do it on grails. I have a huge table (with columns colA, colB, ..., colZ) that I only want to map some of them as fields (say colA, colC, colE) like a database view, this domain class is intended to be read-only so it would not be a problem to not have the save, update and delete operations.

How should I create my domain class?

**EDIT**

I need to adapt a query to a domain object, this query has a lot of group by expressions (max, min, count, etc.) and I would like to adapt this query so that everytime I call DomainObj.list() Grails would run this query and load all the data from the database within the GORM proxy.

Answer (score 4):

If it is read only, just create a domain object containing the fields you are interested in. That should be no problem.

Remember however that GORM will create a "version" column as default, but this can be disabled:

```
static mapping = {
      table 'people'
      version false
}
```

Comment: But how would I call the list method? I'm need to run a custom query on the list method that will execute a query with some group by expressions and filtered fields I talked on the question. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: assuming you mapped it correctly. Then other queries should work. i.e. list, named queries, etc... If your question is how to do the actual queries then maybe you can check the docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.2%20Criteria)

Comment: In this case a database view might be the best solution. GORM will only let you query the fields you have mapped.